# Symfony2.5 and assetic: rewrite javascripts without comments

Tags: symfony, assetic

As title says, I am using Symfony2.5 and assetic.

Is there a way to exclude comments from being inserted when dumping javascritp files?

For example, in my twig I have something like this:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts 
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/javascriptfile.js' 
    %}
      <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

`javascriptfile.js` contains some commented code (some trial code, comments for readability...) that I would like not to be inserted in the version sent to the final user (first of all, smaller size of pages).

However, everything is copied when doing

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

or

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev
```

Is rewriting without comments possible in some way?
Even excluding console.logs would be appreciated...
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can configure yui_js which minifies all your javascript code. There is even an entry of this on the official Symfony website: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html. As far as I know this will remove all comments but not remove the console.log statements

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for. I will bear console.logs. Thank you very much!